# Loop SQL Query For Specific Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query that I need to loop through the system views `sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_exec_sessions` every 60 seconds to pull specific information and dump it into a separate table. After a specified time I would like it to kill the loop. How would the loop be formatted?

Comment: Why do you need to loop instead of selecting your results into a separate table?

Comment: I need to check these every 60 seconds for say an hour for new connections so they can be documented. This way we know exactly what is connecting to the databases.

Comment: Then write a simple query that selects your results into a table, save it as a stored procedure, and then run that from a SQL job on whatever schedule you need.  No loop is required.

Comment: If I connect, query, and disconnect **during** a given minute, your scan might not detect me. You might be better off using SQL Profiler, tracking the login event.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a SQL Agent job. If so, the short form of the answer is:

- Create the job with one step that runs the query
- Add a Schedule that runs it once a minute, starting whenever you want it to start
- Set the schedule to stop running it when the cut-off time is reached

The long form, of course, is all the detail work behind creating a SQL Agent job. Best to read up on them in Books Online ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in a loop. Do it with a [job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx).

Write a sproc that does the query and save the results and then call it from a job.

Comment: Awesome! That will be easier to set up then a loop. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a job as well. But some work environments that is not practical. So you could have something like:

```
WHILE @StopTime < getdate()
BEGIN
   exec LogCurrentData

   WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';  -- wait 1 minute

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is creating a **Job**

- There is a post that explain how to create a job step by step (with images) in SQL Server. 
  [You can visit the post here](http://bit.ly/1gHqaAP)
- If you prefer a video tutorial, you can [visit this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dWGa3P665M)